# Replicate django admin for plain users

Tags: django

I would like to replicate django admin and its functionality for plain users(not staff memebers). So data models that I have would be shown in tables like in django admin, with filters and sortings per column. Even the look(templates) would be the same or similar. Also login and registration should be the same. How could I replicate that without doing it all from ground up, making views, templates etc?

Answer (score -1):

Django admin is limit to the users who the `is_staff = True`.

It might be better to make a page in regular Django views and create the behavior you want according, eg make login required for the page or pages.

There is a few ways you can accomplish this:

1 in urls:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('is_loggedin/', login_required(GenericTestView.as_view())),
]
```

2 decorators on function based views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def restricted_view(request):
    return render(request, 'template.html', {})
```

3 login mixin for Class Based Views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class GenericTestView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = '/home/'
```